# Case in select using Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

How can I make a simple case in a select statement like the following using Slick?

```
SELECT company_name,
       country,
       CASE WHEN country = 'USA' THEN 'domestic'
            ELSE 'foreign' END AS is_domestic
  FROM companies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find something similar, although not exactly the same:
[How to return compound types in Slick's Case-If-Then-Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383717/how-to-return-compound-types-in-slicks-case-if-then-else)

In your case:

```
val query = companies.map{ c =>
  Case If(c.country === "USA") Then "domestic" Else "foreign"
}.result

db.run(query)
```

In offitial docs: [Slick Case](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.1/sql-to-slick.html#case)

Comment: thanks. How did I miss that in the official Slick docs is beyond my understanding :)

Comment: @namesy haha is slowly, with patience you will understand